# How can I install sl4a modules without internet access?

Tags: android, sl4a

I have the necessary `.zip` files in the root directory of `/sdcard`. The language installers insist on using the internet. I'm thinking the `.zip` files are in the incorrect directory. What directory do I put the files; or if that is the wrong question, how can I get any of the `sl4a` languages installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget that those files are even available for download. Use the built-in mandatory installer only after giving up at trying to integrate sl4a into my Eclipse workspace; because there is already a free distribution of Python in the Google Play store :)

Answer (score 0):

sl4a supports `.yak files` . sl4a works on Android Emulator as well.To use, use adb install `sl4a_rnn.apk`